# Problem with a JS code that delays generating elements/divs

Tags: javascript, delay, fadein

I have a problem with JS code that suppose to delay showing certain elements on the website that im currently designing.

Link to website: https://parlourplaces.de

JS Code:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          // Hide the div
          $(".header_desktop").hide();
          // Show the div after 5s
          $(".header_desktop").delay(3500).fadeIn(1000);  
      });
      
      $(document).ready(function () {
          // Hide the div
          $(".slider_main").hide();
          // Show the div after 5s
          $(".slider_main").delay(6000).fadeIn(2000);  
      });
</script>
```

Main menu and slider should fade in after specific time. Function works properly.

Problem is that one line is breaking lots of stuff on my website. For example mobile menu is not showing up after click, or modals also doesent want to work.

Problematic line:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
```

Is there any other way to correct the code or change it to diffirent one so the problematic line wont be included? Without it, fade in function with delay is not working at all, and if I include it, then some functionality of Oxygen Builder doesn't work.

Thanks for all help in advance! Cheers!

Comment: It seems you want to use jQuery but not include it..? Why is including it problematic? Can you upload a minimal example on jsFiddle or CodePen? Are there browser console errors?

Comment: Yeah, im a begginer and still trying to figure out how to deal with JS in webdesign.
I think ive solved my problem quite fast, but not really intentionally. I switched problematic line to this one: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Suddenly everything works, and my small JS code is still working properly. Dont know what was wrong with previous src link.

Comment: Ah you selected version 1.11.3 in your problematic code and your new snippet uses 3.5.1 - that is a difference.